# Найти количество страниц книги, если дана сумма цифр номеров страниц

Tags: алгоритм

Здравствуйте. Есть такая интересная задачка:

> Сумма цифр номеров страниц в книге равна `1050`.
>       Сколько страниц в книге?

Как просчитать ответ?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73848/discussion-on-question-by--------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У каждого числа, обозначающего страницу, имеется цифра на месте единиц. При n страниц имеется n цифр, стоящих на месте единиц. У всех, за исключением первых 9 страниц, числа являются как минимум двухзначными. Поэтому добавим еще n-9 цифр. У всех, за исключением первых 99 страниц, числа являются трехзначными, что добавляет еще n-99 цифр.
n+(n-9)+(n-99) = 1050
при его решении получаем 386.
Видимо, не на всех страницах стоял номер...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75296/discussion-on-answer-by--------).

Answer (score 3):

Пример на **С++**.

*Короткий алгоритм:* Я находил сумму всех цифр чисел страниц, пока эта сумма не равна данному числу (1050).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int get_number_sum(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        sum += n % 10; // Суммируем последнюю цифру
        n /= 10;       // делим на 10, чтобы пройтись на другой десяток числа
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    int out = 1050;   // Число, которое дано

    int i = 3, sum = 0;
    while (sum < out) {
        sum += get_number_sum(i); // Ищем сумму цифр страницы
        i++;
    }

    cout << i + 2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Ответ: 128**.

*@Akina* хорошо заметил, что все номера страниц в книге начинаются с **3**, таким образом начинаем считать с `i = 3`, ну и в конце прибавляем ещё первую и вторую страницы.

Comment: только вот для 1050 ответа нет....

Comment: 124→1045; 125→1053

Comment: @Fat-Zer, я просто предложил вариант решения. Да, я знаю, что оно не совсем так как надо.. но! Хорошо, сейчас поправим.

Comment: @entithat то есть не 124 будет? не могу понять тогда

Comment: @Денис, ну например, если число **44**, то страниц буде меньше 9, но больше 8.. Попробуйте просуммировать сами. `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 45`, а мы хотим для 44, тоесть уже -1 страница, `44 - 8 = 36`, это будет 8 страниц, но у нас число и не **45** и не **36**

Comment: *Точный ответ мы дать не можем.* ROFL. Возьмите любую книгу и посмотрите, с какой страницы начинается нумерация.

Comment: Уже взяли и посмотрели? судя по непониманию - нет.

Comment: В любой БУМАЖНОЙ книге нумерация страниц (цифрами номеров страниц, в смысле) начинается с третьей страницы.

Comment: @Akina, получается 126 страниц. Но это начиная с третьей, тоесть теперь ещё добавить первую и вторую..ведь так? И будет **128**..

Comment: Ну ты ж сам посчитал, что сумма цифр всех чисел от 1 до 125 равна 1053. Соответственно сумма всех цифр чисел от 3 до 125 равна 1050 (1053-1-2). Т.е. ответ - 125. Впрочем, ответ по определению не очень корректен - количество страниц в книге (если это не голимый самиздат) должно быть кратно как минимум 8 (а обычно - 32).

Comment: @Akina, да, иметь нечётное кол-во страниц как минимум странно. Очень легко запутаться в задачах такого типа.

Comment: Кто-то очень хитрый ставит минусы и не отзывается..

Comment: сумма цифр для номеров страниц от 3 до 125 (включительно) равна 1050. То есть количество *нумерованных* страниц: `125-3+1 == 123`. Номер старшей страницы `125`. Как 128 получили не ясно.

Comment: @jfs, если начинать считать с 3 страницы, то для 1050 получаем 126 страниц (без первой и второй). Мне кажется, что само условие задачи некорректно, ибо возможно имели ввиду найти кол-во страниц книги без тех страниц, сумма цифр номеров которых не делают число, которое не будет равно сумме например начиная со страниц первой и второй, или даже третьей...

Comment: @entithat нет, я явно написал же уже 123 (нумерованные страницы). Посмотрите на случай `3` — у нас единственная страница с номером `3` (формула для количества нумерованных страниц: 3-3+1). Сумма цифр для 1..125 (включая) равна 1053, если убрать 1, 2, то будет 1050, то есть от 3..125 получаем 1050: то есть 125-3+1=123 нумерованных страницы.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант в лоб, который если запустить, покажет, что `1050` не является суммой цифр номеров страниц в книге, если страницы с `1` нумеруются. Если начать нумеровать страницы с `3`, то номер старшей страницы `125`, то есть количество нумерованных страниц `123`:

```js
/** Decimal digital sum */
function sum_of_digits(i) {
  var sum = 0
  while (i > 0) {
    sum += i % 10
    i = Math.floor(i / 10)
  }
  return sum
}

/** Find *n* such that sum of digits of number from *start* to n (including) 
  * is *digits_sum*
  */
function find_n(digits_sum, start=1) {
  // brute force
  var sum = 0
  for (var i = start; ; ++i) {
     sum += sum_of_digits(i)
     if (sum == digits_sum) {
       return i
     } else if (sum > digits_sum) {
       throw RangeError(`${digits_sum} can't be the sum of digits from ${start} to n`)
     }
  }
}

var start = 3
console.log(find_n(1050, start=start) - start + 1)
```

Подход с использованием рекурсии ([Sum of digits of number from 1 to n](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/817038/1665)):

```js
/** Decimal digital sum */
function sum_of_digits(i) {
  var sum = 0
  while (i > 0) {
    sum += i % 10
    i = Math.floor(i / 10)
  }
  return sum
}

/** Sum of the digital sum of i for i from 0 to n.
  *
  * https://oeis.org/A037123
  */
function D(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return 0
  }
  console.assert(n > 0, n)
  // n = 10*q + r
  var q = Math.floor(n / 10),
      r = n % 10;
  return 45*q + 10*D(q - 1) + r*(r+1)/2 + (r+1)*sum_of_digits(q)
}

/** Find *n* such that sum of digits of number from *start* to n (including)
  *  is *digits_sum*
  */
function find_n(digits_sum, start=1) {
  for (var i = start; ; ++i) {
     var sum = D(i) - D(start - 1)
     if (sum == digits_sum) {
       return i
     } else if (sum > digits_sum) {
       throw RangeError(`${digits_sum} can't be the sum of digits from ${start} to n`)
     }
  }
}

var start = 3
console.log(find_n(1050, start=start) - start + 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Арифметическая прогрессия с `a^(n) = a^(n-1) + 1;`
У нас есть сумма членов, а из формулы `S^(n) = (2 * a^(1) + d* ( n - 1) ) *n / 2;`
Следовательно `2a^(1) + dn^2 -d = 2S`
`n^2 +2n -2101 = 0;`
`n = +-44.8475`;
Похоже, сумма страниц несколько неверна:)
** ^(n) значок индекса, если формулы не понятны, в гугле есть более понятные если необходимо)
Проверим для 45 ст:

```js
var a = 0;
for ( var i = 1; i <= 45; i++) {
a += i;
}
console.log('сумма страниц = ', a);
```

Comment: Сумма **цифр** номеров страниц.